# Storing float values in internal storage android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a new to Android development and I trying to learn storing and retrieve data stored in internal memory. For this I have included a Line chart which plots x and y coordinates. I've manually entered the coordinate values, for testing purpose once the values get plotted I want store these values in a file.
Later, when i reopen the app if there are any old values those values should be plotted first and later the manually entered values should be plotted.

I have implemented the same using the following code:

```
public static void generateValues(ArrayList<Float> theList) {
    for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); j++) {
         if (dummyValues.size() == 0) {
            dummyValues.add(j, theList.get(j));
          } else if (dummyValues.size() == theList.size()) {
                dummyValues.set(j, theList.get(j));
           } else {
                  dummyValues.add(theList.get(j));
                   }
          }   
               arraySize=dummyValues.size();
          return;
    }
```

I store the x and y values in an Arraylist before plotting the values. Later I plot the values as follows:

```
public void generateData() {
    List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
    dummyValues.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < dummyValues.size(); i++) {
         values.add(new PointValue(i, dummyValues.get(i)));         
         Line line = new Line(values);
         lines.add(line);
         }
     data = new LineChartData(lines);    
     if (hasAxes) {
        Axis axisX = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
        axisX.setEnabled(true);
        axisX.setDrawGridLines(true);
        Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
        axisY.setDrawGridLines(true);
        if (hasAxesNames) {
           axisX.setName("Days");
           axisY.setName("Temeperature(Celsius)");
          }
        data.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
        data.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
        } else {
               data.setAxisXBottom(null);
               data.setAxisYLeft(null);
               }
        data.setBaseValue(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        chart.setLineChartData(data);
}
```

Next, I want store the plotted values in the internal storage. Once the application is opened the old values stored must be plotted first and then the new values should be plotted. So, I want to know which method is best suited for storing and retrieving data from the phone.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Store x,y values in file with data-time and while open app compare files and float based dates order :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store `JSON` format of your values in `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve it but first you need to add `Gson` library to your project. You need to go to your `build.gradle` file and add the following line in `dependencies` section:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

Now use `Gson` to convert your array into `JSON` format (suppose you have an array called `myarraylist`):

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(myarraylist);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.edit().putString("old_data",json).commit();
```

When ever you want to retrieve your old data you can simply do it in reverse like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String json = prefs.getString("old_data","");
TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>>() {};
ArrayList<Float> oldValues = new Gson().fromJson(json,token.getType());
```

At this point `oldValues` contains your old `ArrayList`

Comment: The information you provided is really helpful. But, I want to know does these oldValues get erased after closing the app.

Comment: @ADI no, everything in SharedPreferences remains after closing the app

Comment: I know it's very trivial question but when I include " compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'   "  in "build.gardle I get the following error:                                                                                                               Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'hellocharts-android-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
 The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.                                                 I don't know what went wrong

Comment: @ADI you should add it in the "dependencies" section of your build.gradle

Comment: Yes, I did add it. There are three "build.gradle".First, in project gradle, in which i got the above error. Second are 2 modules one is for the app and the other is for the lineChart library. When I remove it from the main project and include it in the other two build.gradle i get the  following error                                                                                  "Error:(20, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
Show in File  Show in Project Structure dialog    "                                                             Let me where am i going wrong

Comment: @ADI add repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} to your build.gradle root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109012/discussion-between-pooya-and-adi).

Comment: I just have some more doubts.. that's why i reopened the question

Comment: Just a curious question... what do i need to do if i need to store the values on the phone without overwriting the values?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use SharedPreferences. It is Key-Value pair storage. and you cant put float value in SharedPreferrence so use Double or String type to store values

Comment: it is an array of values not a single value

Comment: You can use PutStringSet() method to store array

Comment: yes but first it is added in API 11 and second you need to convert your datatyype to HashSet or something similar